# Timber (twig), loop parent

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I use Timber (twig) with Wordpress and ACF.

I would like to create this structure :

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="slide slide0">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="home" data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide1">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="2" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="3" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
      <div class="slide slide0">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide1">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="2" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="3" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

But for `data-type` attribute I need to add home for the first section and project to the other. I try with parent loop index but that's don't work.

```
data-type="{% if loop.parent.loop.index0 %}home{% else %}project{% endif %}"
```

In the context :

```
{% for section in sections %}
            <div class="section" id="section{{ loop.index }}">
                {% for slide in section.get_field('project_imgs') %}
                  <div class="slide slide{{ loop.index0 }}">
                      <div class="image-container" data-type="{% if loop.parent.loop.index0 %}home{% else %}project{% endif %}" data-currentslide="{{ loop.index }}" data-maxslides="{{ section.get_field('project_imgs')|length }}" data-title="{{ section.project_title }}" data-project="{{ section.project_legend }}">
                          <img src="{{site.theme.link}}/assets/img/samples/mac-web.jpg">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you see my answer @Xroad?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a comparison to "0" plus also do an `and` on the second loop index:

```
data-type="{% if loop.parent.loop.index0 == 0 and loop.index0 == 0 %}home{% else %}project{% endif %}"
```

Here is a twigfiddle to show the part that you are concerned about working:
https://twigfiddle.com/n9ucvn